# DataGrip Not Recognizing PostgreSQL data types

Tags: postgresql, datagrip

I have set my DataGrip database project to use the latest PostgreSQL dialect and driver, yet nowhere does it understand the PostgreSQL data types natively. For example, it will autocomplete `varchar` but not `text`.

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/datatype.html

Is it just not capable of this?

EDIT: Another example is the "Generate DDL" for a table will create a statement with `uuid(max)` instead of simply `uuid`.

Comment: don't know what You're saying. datagrip understands well data types in my 10.x.x postgres server. see screenshot: http://joxi.ru/5mdGG4tk9gjwr1

Comment: if autocomplete does not show text when You use console - write feature request to JetBrains about it.

Comment: @num8er can you tell/show me if "text" comes up in the list of types when creating a column in that create a table screen you posted?

Comment: Nope it does not come in autocomplete, I agree with You. But why You so worried if You've familiarity with db? (:

Comment: Was looking to buy this product, but there's no need if it doesn't actually make things faster. :) Thanks for your help!

Comment: Actually I have monthly subscription from JetBrains that gives access to dev tools. DataGrip is in list of them. But I must say DG is best all-in-one relational database tool for now. Yes it has few features that may not exist, but in total I've enough db exp and I'm comfortable with DG even if it does not autocomplete somethings.

Comment: Please, share a screenshot of a problem

Comment: The solution ended up being NOT having the "introspect using JDBC metadata" option enabled. Not quite clear what that option even does, based on the docs. https://www.jetbrains.com/help/datagrip/data-sources-and-drivers-dialog.html#optionsTab

Answer (score 4, accepted):

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/datagrip/data-sources-and-drivers-dialog.html#optionsTab

The solution was to disable "Introspect using JDBC metadata". Thanks @num8er for their help.